# Colocar en parámetro OUT de procedimiento almacenado mysql sumatoria de campo de una tabla

Tags: mysql, stored-procedure, sum, parámetros

Dentro de un **procedimiento almacenado** mysql tengo:

-**@timporte**: parámetro OUT

-**temporal**: tabla generada en el procedimiento

-**importe**: campo de la tabla temporal

Tras la generación de la tabla temporal **necesito colocar en @timporte la sumatoria de valores del campo importe**. Intento sin éxito, entre otras, con la siguiente sintaxis:

**select @timporte =  sum(importe) from temporal2;**

¿Alguien me podría ayudar con la sintaxis correcta?

Comment: ¿Revisaste el primer ejemplo de la [documentación](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html)?

Comment: haces select de `temporal2`, pero antes dices que la tabla se llama `temporal`.

Comment: @jachguate: La tabla es temporal2. Omití el "2" al indicarla la primera vez